# flexbox:last-of-type not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, flexbox

I've several flexboxes in a container - they all have a margin-bottom of e.g. 40px - I'd like to get rid of the margin of the last flexbox within that container - .flexbox:last-of-type does not work - same for :first-of-type, :last-child.

Am I missing something here - hope somebody can help.

Thank you in advance for your input.

---

I'm actually referring to something like this:

```
   <div class="container">
<div class="flex">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="flex">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="flex">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
</div>
```

targeting the last .flex with .flex:last-of-type doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Those pseudo-classes work, ass seen in the following example:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
span {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

However, it might be that you use a row layout and the last line contains more than one flex-item. Then, even if you remove the margin of the last flex-item, it will seem it still has margin because of the margin of the other flex-items in that line.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 64px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
span {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

To avoid that problem, you can add a negative margin to the flex container to neutralize the margin of the last row, and then place the flex container inside another wrapper with `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 64px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
span {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="flex">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```